# How to set if condition in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

so i am new to bash scripting and trying to setup my first conditional block. I am using a shell script to get a JSON response and when the returned item is 0 i want it to do something.

```
QUEUE_SIZE=$(curl url | jq '.items | length')

if ["$QUEUE_SIZE" -eq "0"]
then
   echo "Hey this is cool!!"
fi
```

When i run the above script, i get the following error: `line 3: [0: command not found`

Can someone please correct what i'm doing wrong? Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: For future reference; if you copy and paste that into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/ ) you get answers for questions like yours ... (and end up doing less typing)

Comment: @tink Thanks for that!! that would be helpful

Comment: Thanks guys. It was a matter of adding space. I see now what i was doing wrong!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor revision:

```
#!/bin/bash

QUEUE_SIZE=$(curl url | jq '.items | length')

if [ "$QUEUE_SIZE" == "0" ]; then
   echo "Hey this is cool!!"
fi
```

Comment: Heyy!! Nice. Thank you, It worked

Comment: Use `=` not `==` -- the latter is not POSIX-specified and not guaranteed to work on all shells (and several `/bin/sh` implementations don't support it; we have questions from their users in our knowledge base). Even when your shell is known to be bash, better to be in the habit of writing more broadly-compatible code when there's no concrete benefit to be gained by doing otherwise.